# Exe does not work without application config file

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a very simple application which queries the database, gets the relevant data and displays it to the end users. I am using `EntityFramework` to query my database and I've got a connection string in the `app.config` file. Everything works perfectly fine. When I build the project and use the `exe` from the release directory it works as expected, however if I move the `exe` to another directory and try to run it I get an error message saying

> No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file

So my question is do I have to include the `app.config` file with my application exe to whoever uses it or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you would usually also supply the app.config unless you had a good reason not to.

Comment: @JustinHarvey What about the sensitive information in the connection string?

Comment: So this is what I meant by a good reason.  If you don't want to expose this then you will have to encrypt the data or store the information elsewhere.

Comment: @Downvoter care to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your application, `app.config` is copied to `AppName.exe.config` in the same directory as the executable `AppName.exe`.

This file needs to be copied along with your executable.

In general, you should copy all files from the output folder along with the executable.  Such files may include referenced assemblies which will be needed to run the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what about the sensitive information in the connection string like password? You can just right click and open the file and view its content right?

Comment: @Code, yes, you will be able to view the file content including sensitive information such as passwords.  You can encrypt or obfuscate the sensitive information, but a determined attacker will still be able to decrypt it if he can run the executable.  You might consider using Windows authentication for your database connection to obviate the need to store a password.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to expose this then you will have to encrypt the data or store the information elsewhere.  Have a look at this for the encryption approach.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx